# CURL successful login redirecting to login page again

Tags: php, html, dom, cross-domain

I am trying to get a value of some fields from my other domain.
The other domain site has a login page. I am doing successful login in browser and the calling the file_get_contents() function but still it is returning me login page HTML.

I want HTML of the page which I am passing in URL.

Here is my code after adding cookie file

```
$COOKIEFILE = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt';
$formFields['username']  = 'XXXXXX';
$formFields['password']  = 'XXXXXX';
$ch = curl_init();

// set some options on the handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $COOKIEFILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $COOKIEFILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.mydomain.lcl/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($formFields));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Second Request after login

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.mydomain.lcl/dashboard');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Can anyone plz suggest me how to bypass login page and access the HTML of a page.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` on your server is completely unrelated to the login / session in your browser. You need to use cURL on the server  to login at the remote server and then get the page as a logged-in user.

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing successful login in browser

… so now the **browser** can access the page behind the login.

> and the calling the file_get_contents()

Your PHP program is not the browser. It doesn't have access to the page behind the login.

You need to login using an HTTP request you make from PHP (and then store whatever the login system expects you to send back with each request … probably a cookie).

Comment: Hey Quentin. I did the same plz see my updated code. hee sending a cookie in a subsequent request but still, it redirects me to a login page.